# How do I make a <li> list hidden before showing?

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

Im trying to help a friend with his project.

The website has this `<li>` list with some apartments.

You can see it here: http://karberghus.dk.linux5.unoeuro-server.com

But the first time your visiting the website you can see a long list with apartments instead of the horizontal jquery carousel.

Is it possible to fix this ugly loading of the apartments?

Comment: sounds like script/stylesheet optimization issues.  You might want to consider making sure the stylesheets and and the javascript files are grouped separately.

Comment: Javascript and CSS isn´t they allways grouped seperately? Its two different things so how can it be mixed?

Comment: They can be mixed in that you can have in your header `script, stylesheet, script, script, stylesheet`.  they need to be grouped together like `stylesheet, stylesheet, script, script, script`.  When I opened the page it didn't show the described problem, and if you get inconsistent results like that (sometimes working and sometimes not) it's likely something is not fully loading.  Ordering scripts and stylsheets can help with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the `<ul>` class to a css style that has

```
display: none
```

set on it, or alternatively create an inline style of

```
style = 'display: none'
```

so when it first loads, it's invisible.

Then, in your jquery

```
$(document).ready(...)
```

function, you can hook up your carousel plugin and either remove the css class that makes it hidden or remove the inline style to make it visible again.

-m

Comment: Mustafakidd kan you send me a PM ?

Answer (score 1):

Set an inline style on the `<ul>` to hide it initially (`<ul style="display: none">`, which you can then override later on after the page has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to name the `<ul>` (maybe `<ul id="mylist">`) and show it when ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 if (<some condition>) {
   $('#mylist').show();
 }
}
```

Comment: I will first try with by adding this example..

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#block-views-homepage-jcarousel-block').jcarousel();
});

</script>